# Miscellaneous ways to get higher pagerank

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, pagerank, blog

I would like to get higher pagerank for my blog.
I know good contents are most important for SEO.
But I guess there are miscellaneous things(but legal) which site operators should know.

These are something I wanted to know.

- What if I send a tracback to someone else's blog, does it help my blog's pagerank?
- If I register a comment to other blogs(with my blog address), does it help my blog's pagerank?
- http://benjaminlog.com/ <- I just wrote my blog address at here. does it help my blog's pagerank?
- If I send a tracback to someone's blog which is very famous, does it help my blog's pagerank **much more**?
- If I register a comment to other blogs which is very famous, does it help my blog's pagerank **much more**?
- If I write a post at newsgroup(include blog address to my signature), does it help my blog's pagerank?

If you have any tips else, please answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What if I send a tracback to someone else's blog, does it help my blog's pagerank?

[Trackbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trackback) are intended to notify another blog owner when you have created a link to his or her blog. Without a link to the blog in question, a trackback from your blog is meaningless and may very well be considered spam.

Note that most modern blogging platforms allow trackback moderation - there's a very good chance your trackback will not be displayed unless you actually linked to the blog in question.

> If I register a comment to other
>   blogs(with my blog address), does it
>   help my blog's pagerank?

Perhaps a little bit, however, many blog owners (as a result of continuous comment spam) now use Javascript-powered comment widgets like [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) and many bloggers designate comment links as [nofollow links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow).

> I just wrote my blog address at here.
>   does it help my blog's pagerank?

View source on this page and see for yourself. (Hint: `rel="nofollow"`)

> If I send a tracback to someone's blog
>   which is very famous, does it help my
>   blog's pagerank much more?

See first answer.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. If there is rel="nofollow", is it definitly meaningless for SEO?

Comment: Correct. However it doesn't necessarily make it worthless - if you write a well informed post/response it can be a useful way of attracting traffic to your site.

Answer (score 1):

If you want higher PageRank you need to get more links to point to your pages (web sites don't have PageRank, pages do). The only way to increase your PageRank is with links as PageRank is a numerical representation of link popularity. Nothing else affects PageRank.

If you want to increase your page's rank then you need to follow the basic principles of SEO which have been rehashed countless times here and on many websites.

Answer (score 0):

I have **NO IDEA** how google's rankings work, but my guess would be that it would greatly help your cause to have English translations in an */en/* directory.  Although I'm sure google.jp would have no problem ranking your page high if it was benjaminlog.jp, I would guess, since the official language of the US is English, that it greatly favors English-language web sites when people located in the US use google.com (as opposed to google.jp, etc.,) which accounts for probably 99% of all google searches here in the US.

It only makes sense that since I live in the US, if I were to search for *Vladimir Putin*, I would get web sites in English, since I, and pretty much every other American, would have no use for a site about Putin that is in Russian.  Similarly, even if someone in Japan were to search for something that might be on your web site, I would guess that google would still slightly favor .jp sites over .com sites, since .jp sites are far more likely to be owned and hosted by people in Japan.

Another problem with your web site is that it uses no meta keywords or description.  Although meta keywords and descriptions won't, in and of themselves, boost your page rank considerably, they should definitely help a little.

(Note: My web site ranks first on google if you search for the appropriate technical term, which is also the domain name itself.  I'm sure that helps my cause, but it was obviously insufficient, in your case, to bump you up to #1, or even the first page, for the searches *benjamin log* and *benjaminlog*.  How I managed to get #1, I have no idea, but I'm not complaining!  Like I said, though, I'd blame your low page rank mostly on the language issues and the lack of meta info..)

Comment: But it's impossible. I don't have ability to write a post in English. It is not Japanese though, it's Korean. Thanks anyway.

Comment: My fault... it shows up as random, unknown characters on my system.  :)  Not sure if you saw it or not, but I edited later to add another point: the lack of meta keywords & description.  At any rate, why are you unable to post anything in English?  You seem to be able to write English quite well.  You wouldn't have to change your home page to English, merely translate your blog posts into English and place them in an */en/* directory, linked on the home page.

Comment: I didn't know about meta keyword. I didn't care about that. I guess my blog engine does not support making meta keyword. Is Wordpress optimized for SEO?

Comment: I have no idea how WP works, but it can't do everything.  Meta data helps search engines identify what a web site is about.  If someone searches for certain keywords, and if those words match your meta keywords, your web site is listed as being relevant.  You should be able to enter meta data somehow, whether it be through wordpress or by directly editing the HTML.  Here's an example of what you might use: <meta name="keywords" content="benjamin, log, benjaminlog, programming, computers" >
<meta name="description" content="Benjamin's blog about computers and programming!" >

Comment: Aha, understood. My blog engine has a interface to modify default skin(HTML). I'm trying. Thank you.